# Finding word co-occurrences

Tags: python, word-count

So here is my problem.  I have a very large csv file that has 3 columns.  The first column is unique ids.  The second column is a string that is an english sentence.  The third column is a string of word tags that describe the sentence in the second column (usually 3 tags, max of 5).  Here is an example.

```
id | sentence                       | tags
1  | "people walk dogs in the park" | "pet park health"
2  | "I am allergic to dogs"        | "allergies health"
```

What I want to do is find all of the co-occurrences of tag words with words in sentences. So the desired output for the above example would look something like.

```
("walk","pet"),1
("health","dogs"),2
("allergies","dogs"),1
etc...
```

where the first entry is a word pair (the first from the sentence, the second is a tag word) and then the number of times they co-occur.

I am wondering what the best way to do this is.  I was thinking perhaps I could come up with a python dictionary where the key is a tag word and the value is the set of ids where that tag word appears.  I could do the same with all of the words that appear in all sentences (after removing stop-words).  Then I could count the number of ids in the intersection of both sets for every combination of the two words which would give me the number of times they co-occur.

However, this seems like it would take a very long time (huge csv file!).  I also might run out of memory.  Can anyone think of a better way to do this.  Maybe import the file into a database and run some sort of query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's easy with [itertools.product()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [collections.Counter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import csv
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

rdr = csv.reader(open(r"data.csv"), quotechar='"',delimiter='|')
c = Counter((x, y) for _, a, b in rdr for x, y in product(a.split(), b.split()))
```

As for processing huge file, I think you can try some kind of map-reduce - read csv line by line and save all combinations into another file:

```
with open(r"data.csv") as r, open(r"data1.csv", "w") as w:
    rdr = csv.reader(r, quotechar='"', delimiter='|')
    for _, a, b in rdr:
        for x, y in product(a.split(), b.split()):
            w.write("{},{}\n".format(x, y))
```

Next step would be to read second file and create counter:

```
with open(r"c:\temp\data1.csv") as r:
    for l in r:
        c[l.rstrip('\n')] += 1
```

**update** I've started to see is there any map-reduce framework for Python. Here's first link by googling - [Disco map-reduce framework](http://discoproject.org/). Actually it has a [tutorial](http://disco.readthedocs.org/en/latest/start/tutorial.html) which shows how to create and run a Disco job that counts words - I think it could be useful for you (at least I will go and give it a try :) ). And another one - https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give this a try.  Just one question.  When you say map-reduce, are you talking about using multiple clusters?  Because I do not have access to that.

Comment: @user1893354 I'm not in any way guru of big clusters too, may be I should not use words map-reduce. What I mean is more streamlike processing. If you don't have enough memory to load all data from file, you can load it line by line, save tuples to file, then run another program to count tuples. I think it could also be useful to load this splitted data to SQL and count frequences there (you can build indexes to speed up process)

Comment: That's what I had thought.  I just wanted to clarify.  Thanks!